# Is there a chronological order for Father Brown stories?

Tags: g-k-chesterton, father-brown, timeline

I've read most of the Father Brown stories, and I noticed a bit of time travelling takes place in them (not sci-fi time-travelling, but an ambivalence by the author to the fact that somethings couldn't have taken place while Father Brown was the rector of such-and-such parish or performing miracles in South America).

In any event, has any aficionado compiled a chronological order of G.K. Chesterton's Father Brown stories, and do any of Chesterton's other novels fit in the timeline?

Comment: It'd be nice to have a "[tag:chronological-order]" or "[tag:chronology]" I don't want to use "[tag:reading-order]" because I don't think it much helps to read the stories in any particular order.

Comment: [BookSeriesInOrder.com](https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/father-brown/) only lists the publication order. [OrderOfBooks.com](https://www.orderofbooks.com/characters/father-brown/) claims that publication order is chronological order.

Comment: @rand I guess that's possible, just didn't seem likely.  Maybe a closer read would explain why it's possible.  It could be that the stories that appear out of order were presented as flashbacks.

Comment: I have great affection for Chesterton, but I doubt he ever thought twice about chronology ... I believe he came up with an idea, and then thought of a reason for Father Brown to be where he was needed. 
In the same way, *The Paradoxes of Mister Pond* includes some excellent stories, but they tell us very little about the career of Mr Pond.

Comment: Would you please cite a few examples of things that couldn't have happened.